# Unable to handle Collection Deserealization Error

Tags: c#, collections, json.net

I'm trying to handle deresealize an object that does not comply with some of my classes. I wold like the code to execute and fail only on the invalid attributes but the deserealization method is returning a null Object.

I am using this method in a generic utility class that deserealizes some string to any given type.

From the test code, the error handler works correctly on invalid dates and other invalid types and returns the object with the default .NET initialization values.

If I change (or comment) the Items collection in the sub object, the code works.

```
string json = "{\"Id\":8,\"CreatedByUserId\":0,\"CreatedOnDate\":\"2019X-Y02Z-W06T18:A51:05.783\",\"LastModifiedByUserId\":1,\"LastModifiedOnDate\":\"2019-03-12T17:00:34.82\",\"OperationData\":{\"IsActive\":true,\"Items\":[{\"_Id\":1,\"Id_Value\":0,\"Id\":1},{\"_Id\":2,\"Id\":2},{\"Id\":1,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"Content\":{}}]}}";

TestType test = DeserealizeContent(json);

/*The convertion utility*/ 
 private static TestType DeserealizeContent(string data)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                Error = HandleDeserializationError
            };
            var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestType>(data, settings);
            return r;
        }
        public static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
        {
            errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }

/*Supporting types*/
public class TestType {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }
        public OperationDataType OperationData {get;set;}
    }

    public class OperationDataType {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

I was expecting the error handler to catch handle the exception and continue with the process but instead the deserealization just returns null in the end.

If I change List Items to List Items the result is correctly parsed.

My expected result wold be:
{
    "Id": 8,
    "CreatedByUserId": 0,
    "CreatedOnDate": null,
    "LastModifiedByUserId": 1,
    "LastModifiedOnDate": "2019-03-12T17:00:34.82",
    "OperationData": {
        "IsActive": true,
        "Items": null
    }
}

**EDIT - workaround**

The suggestion from Yair (bellow) works.
Changing from List to List works as expected and the exception get handle correctly.

Comment: I think my real question is: Why does the incompatible type error breaks all the serealization process instead of being handled and fail only on the items property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in your json is not an array of int so how you want it to be List?
Items is array of objects look at the json formated:

```
{
    "Id": 8,
    "CreatedByUserId": 0,
    "CreatedOnDate": "2019X-Y02Z-W06T18:A51:05.783",
    "LastModifiedByUserId": 1,
    "LastModifiedOnDate": "2019-03-12T17:00:34.82",
    "OperationData": {
        "IsActive": true,
        "Items": [{
                "_Id": 1,
                "Id_Value": 0,
                "Id": 1
            }, {
                "_Id": 2,
                "Id": 2
            }, {
                "Id": 1,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "Content": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can do one of three things:

1. handle the json content as string or map it so the items will be int array [1,2,3].
2. create item class for the items that include all the fields you need then extract the int that you want.
3. get it as object like you do now and use reflection () for getting the int you want.

you can use this function for reflection:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

and then use it  like this:

```
GetPropValue(test.OperationData.items[0], "Id")
```

EDIT
you can use this to deserialize the json in generic way:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jsonDeserialized  = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

and then

you can map it manually or with automapper to the new TestType test that you want without the items in it.

you can get the values like this:

```
test.Id = jsonDeserialized["Id"];
test.CreatedByUserId = jsonDeserialized["CreatedByUserId"];
```

and so on

according to your last comment i find that if i changed the `List<int> Items` to `List<long> Items` it works as you wanted. it is something with primitive types and the parsing that deserialize do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have control of the input json string as i am receiving it from an API. Also, it is ok if some parts of the json do not get parsed correctly (returning null for that given path). My problem is that the full deserealization is returning a null object because there is an issue with a type in a sub class. What I wold like to achieve in this example wold be a generic way of deserealizing everithing except the Items as there is a incompatibility there.

Comment: If you don't want items and you can remove them why don't you just keep it as List of objects. if you still want to remove it you will need to remove it from the string or look at my addition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Yair, your suggestions wold work in any particular case. What I am trying to accomplish here is a deserealisation method that fails gracefully and maps whatever it can from the json string to the given type. Actually, the posted code is just an example to illustrate the failing condition: when a collection fails to deserealize (as in the example list<object> is incompatible with a list<primitive>) the full deserealization method fails. The root cause where I detected this issue was when the type of the collection changed making all the parsing fail because of an inner error.

Comment: So my question is if the code is handling the exception, why does it work everywhere (like in invalid dates) but not in invalid array types?

Comment: Hi I found that it doesn't work good with int from what i read may be because it try to Deserialize it to long so i changed the List<int> Items to List<long> items and it worked and return an empty List. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot Yair, I think we can work with that. I still find it strange that the parser works differently between int and long but your suggestion works and it will be good enough for now. Cheers!